# Installed Ubuntu on a partition and now cannot load windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

When I get to the load screen it just says Ubuntu twice. I had been asked me to do some swap thing and I told it to use the other partition for the swap which I'm guessing is why this happened.

Is there anyway for me to at least get the data off that other partition? Am I doomed? I have the following:

- TOSHIBA 1.6GB NTFS
- 225GB swap space
- 16GB ext3
- Extended 16GB
- HDDRECOVERY 7.8GB NTFS

Comment: Run Ubuntu from the Live CD and report back with what HDDs & Partitions (with type) you now have.

Comment: I'm guessing your windows installation is under that swap space. There are ways to recover data using Ubuntu but I'm not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

Your windows partition has been replaced and reformatted as a swap partition.
I don't know if it is possible to fully revert that but I don't think so. You appear to still have the recovery partition to reinstall windows from factory setup.

Comment: Is swap space formatted?

Comment: yes but there may be ways to recover (but I don't know)

Answer (score 0):

It may look like your Windows Partition was erased, next time you install a different OS for dual boot make sure you label your drives and also stay away from attempting to format NTFS labelled drives to avoid your OS being removed.

You can try using certain data recovery utilities.

Try Photorec for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting Ubuntu and start GParted to see what is really happening. If it's not in your installation, boot your live CD. It very much depends on what type of format you chose.

Some installers don't erase the NTFS, they just null it and write any new data on top of it. There might still be a way to backup everything you need, but it's better not to write anything on that disk -  I would suggest shutting it down and mounting it on another PC if you can.

Comment: Booting the installed ubuntu has got to be a bad idea given that the windows install was probably converted into swap space.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy. Boot from a live CD, open a terminal and run the following commands (assuming the root directory of your installed system is at `/dev/sda5`):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt

grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
update-grub2
grub-install /dev/sda
exit

sudo reboot
```

Comment: -1, read his question...his windows-partition is most likely gone.